# Which one: "I often go watch movies with my friends" or "I often go watch movies with some friends of mine"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to ask native speakers that which one sounds better:

1 - I often go watch movies with my friends.

2 - I often go watch movies with some friends of mine.

I lived in Australia for 13 years & most of time I heard people use (2).

(1) sounds more specific whereas (2) sounds more general. If using (1), then listeners are going to ask "**who your friends are**"

Comment: Why not compare 2 against "I often go watch movies with **some** of my friends"? That way we're all talking about the same amount of people (some) and the same degree of specificity.

Comment: Can you tell us what you think the word _some_ means in this sentence? What kind of word is it?

Comment: Have you tried to actually use one of both of those sentences in a conversation with a native speaker? What was the result?

Answer (score 1):

There are two other versions that haven't been discussed:

1. > I often go to watch movies with **my** friends.
   >   I often go to watch movies with friends.

   A pedant would say "Whose friends?" - but *of course* they're your friends: that's implied!
2. > I often **go to** watch movies with my friends.
   >   I often watch movies with my friends.

   The phrase "go to" implies that you're going to a cinema, rather than watch them at home - even a friend's home.

Combined:

3. > I often watch movies with friends.

This version sounds the most natural to my ears. It doesn't have the extra (unnecessary) "my", and it isn't specific that you actually visit a cinema to watch the movies. You *may*, but if you also watch at home, then this (to me) sounds the most natural.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying for formal English, insert the implied 'to' in both your example statments:

> I often go **to** watch movies with my friends.
>
> I often go **to** watch movies with some friends of mine.

If you then omit the word 'watch' from these sentences they will become:

> I often go to movies with my friends.
>
> I often go to movies with some friends of mine.

These last versions of the sentences have a slightly different meaning, since they don't imply that you actually watched the movie, just that you were there.

If you are less concerned about formal speaking, your original example sentences work just fine.

The difference in meaning between your two example sentences is that the first implies all (or most) of your friends are present, while the second says that only 'some' of your friends are usually at the movies with you.

A listener might ask you who your friends are after either sentence, but they are more likely to ask you which subset of your friends you go to movies with in the case of the second sentence.

Comment: "I often go to movies" - shouldn't it be "to **the** movies"?

Comment: @Rompey: "the movies" implies that there is a single way to watch movies. Using "the" in front of a word implies some unique or singular noun. "The Moon" means the only moon orbiting earth, while "moon" might mean any moon. I believe the usage of "the movies" was more common when the only way to see movies was at movie theatres, but with internet streaming and DVDs it may only be appropriate if you are actually watching the movie at a movie theatre.

Comment: I would agree if it were "I often go to **watch** movies", but your "go to movies" makes me ask you: Is English your native language? If it is, I'll have to post a question about the correctness of what you maintain to be correct.

Comment: @Rompey: yes, English is my native language. I also tend to use it in a precisionist way due to a combination of a computer programming background and many years of reading books, but am probably somewhat deficient in knowledge of modern English slang or usage.